# Strip positional information from subprocess std out

Tags: python, subprocess

I am running a subprocess in python, capturing the std output:

```
results = subprocess.run(my_command, capture_output=True)
```

The command in question uses positional characters to update the number of packets sent, but in the resultant output, eg results.stdout, I see all of the updates.

```
Connecting (1 Packets Sent, 0 Packets Received, 0 Retries)\x1b[2K\r[\x1b[33m  0% \x1b[0m] Connecting (1 Packets Sent, 0 Packets Received, 0 Retries)\x1b[2K\r[\x1b[33m  0% \x1b[0m]
```

Ideally, I only want to save the final output, eg

```
[ERROR] Connecting (194 Packets Sent, 0 Packets Received, 193 Retries)
```

Not every one of the 194 interim lines. Is there a way do decode the stdout to only show the final string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\x1b[2K` is the signal to erase the entire line.  So this will get you the final thing printed:

```
lastline = output.rfind('\x1b[2K')
output = output[lastline+4:]
```

That still leave the other ANSI codes, but since this uses a fixed set, those should be easy to remove.

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping there was something that could act as  a psuedo console and actively "process" the output, but that was probably unreasonable as its just as easy to grep the output looking for the last line.  I was using a search for ERROR, but I like your solution better as it always gives me the last line, even if there wasn't an error.